# moving window and resize bottom flickers

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to make a kind of popup notification window that slides out of the task bar.

At the moment I am only trying to get it to work if the taskbar is on bottom of screen, I have it working like it should.

But the problem im having is when the window is starting to appear/slide the bottom part of it flickers (depending on how big i have set my `m_nIncrement` value, it flashes the bottom area the same size as the `m_nIncrement` value)
The window disappears fine with no flicker.

```
//MyWindow
WNDCLASS wc =
{
    CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, __sWndProcDlg, 0, 0, g_hInst, nullptr,
    LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW), (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH),
    nullptr, m_lpszClassName
};

if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    return;

m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE, m_lpszClassName, NULL, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, m_hWndParent, NULL, g_hInst, NULL);

//ShowWindow
void _ShowWindow(int _show)
{
    unsigned int nDesktopWidth = m_rcDesktop.right - m_rcDesktop.left;
    unsigned int nDesktopHeight = m_rcDesktop.bottom - m_rcDesktop.top;
    unsigned int nScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    unsigned int nScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    BOOL bTaskbarOnRight = nDesktopWidth<nScreenWidth && m_rcDesktop.left == 0;
    BOOL bTaskbarOnLeft = nDesktopWidth<nScreenWidth && m_rcDesktop.left != 0;
    BOOL bTaskBarOnTop = nDesktopHeight<nScreenHeight && m_rcDesktop.top != 0;
    BOOL bTaskbarOnBottom = nDesktopHeight<nScreenHeight && m_rcDesktop.top == 0;

    if (_show)
    {
        ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOW);

        if (bTaskbarOnBottom)
        {
            m_nCurrentPos.cx = m_rcDesktop.right - m_sMaxSize.cx;
            m_nCurrentPos.cy = m_rcDesktop.bottom - m_nCurrentSize.cy;
            m_nTaskbarPlacement = TASKBAR_ON_BOTTOM;
        }


        KillTimer(m_hWnd, IDT_DISAPPEARING);
        SetTimer(m_hWnd, IDT_APPEARING, 1, nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        KillTimer(m_hWnd, IDT_APPEARING);

        if (bTaskbarOnRight)
            m_nCurrentPos.cx = m_rcDesktop.right - m_sMaxSize.cx;
        else if (bTaskbarOnLeft)
            m_nCurrentPos.cx = m_rcDesktop.left;
        else if (bTaskBarOnTop)
            m_nCurrentPos.cy = m_rcDesktop.top;
        else //if (bTaskbarOnBottom)
            m_nCurrentPos.cy = m_rcDesktop.bottom - m_nCurrentSize.cy;

        SetTimer(m_hWnd, IDT_DISAPPEARING, 1, NULL);
    }
}

//__OnTimer
LRESULT __OnTimer(HWND hWnd, UINT nIDEvent)
{
    int m_nIncrement = 20;
    if (nIDEvent == IDT_APPEARING)
    {
        switch (m_nTaskbarPlacement)
        {
        case TASKBAR_ON_BOTTOM:
            if (m_nCurrentPos.cy > (m_rcDesktop.bottom - m_sMaxSize.cy))
            {
                m_nCurrentPos.cy -= m_nIncrement;
                m_nCurrentSize.cy = m_rcDesktop.bottom - m_nCurrentPos.cy;
            }
            else
                KillTimer(hWnd, IDT_APPEARING);

            break;
        }

        SetFocus(hWnd);
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, m_nCurrentPos.cx, m_nCurrentPos.cy, m_sMaxSize.cx, m_nCurrentSize.cy, SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    }
    else if (nIDEvent == IDT_DISAPPEARING)
    {
        switch (m_nTaskbarPlacement)
        {
        case TASKBAR_ON_BOTTOM:
            if (m_nCurrentPos.cy < m_rcDesktop.bottom)
            {
                m_nCurrentPos.cy += m_nIncrement;
                m_nCurrentSize.cy = m_rcDesktop.bottom - m_nCurrentPos.cy;
            }
            else
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, IDT_DISAPPEARING);
                MoveWindow(m_hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, FALSE);
                ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_HIDE);
            }
            break;
        }

        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, m_nCurrentPos.cx, m_nCurrentPos.cy, m_sMaxSize.cx, m_nCurrentSize.cy, SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should list the API that you're programming to in the tags.

Comment: @nobar - what do you consider to not be present? It's using the WinApi - what else could reasonably be expected? (You don't need to target one of a bunch of libraries like you would if using X11, the functionality is right there in user32.dll and comctrl32.dll - both parts of the WinApi)

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Could you format it better please.

Comment: @enhzflep: Just adding the tag `winapi`, as has now been done, is probably good enough.  It's helpful to categorize questions by API, rather than leaving readers to guess.

Comment: But guessing whether this is C or C++ is okay?

Comment: not to sure why i got - votes on this post.

Answer (score 1):

use [AnimateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. it is easy to use. you may need to handle WM_PRINT, and this also is quit straightforward.

if ever you want to keep working on your code then:

1) remove from popup class the flags CS_HREDRAW & CS_VREDRAW

2) handle WM_ERASEBACKGROUND

finally. if it is a popup window, do not call SetFocus(); maybe you have to set zorder to TOP_MOST

good luck

Comment: `AnimateWindow` is a great (the better) suggestion, the remainder of your points also answer the question as posed. Each are worthy of reward.

Comment: Oh wow i didnt know about AnimateWindow. just a quick question, how do i keep my text that i draw in WM_PAINT to show while its doing theanimation?

Comment: draw on WM_PAINT event. as you draw on WM_DRAW. without calling BeginPaint & EndPaint.cast WPARAM to get hdc

Comment: i ended up getting this to work, but once again i had another problem, this time on a black background i get around 3mm white line at the top while this slides. i have googled for hours and cant find any examples doing this

Comment: Try at the end of the animation to force Window to be redrawn use [RedrawWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: once its done the animation it is fine its just during it, it only does it when it goes up, going down is fine, its weird

Comment: The window procedures for the window and its child windows should handle any WM_PRINT or WM_PRINTCLIENT messages. Dialog boxes, controls, and common controls already handle WM_PRINTCLIENT. The default window procedure already handles WM_PRINT.

Comment: sorry about some comments, there is no WM_DRAW but WM_PRINTCLIENT and WM_PRINT

Comment: i already handle WM_PRINTCLIENT and WM_PRINT, as i said i have it printing and drawing my text druing the animation, its just adding a white bar up the top. not sure if its my create window function, im trying to create a window with no borders and no title

Comment: OK, i figured it out :). you know what check this part of the code `GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH)`

Comment: change it to (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1)